# Exclusive compute mode with OpenCL+NVidia

Tags: c, cuda, opencl

I have a question to exclusive compute mode with NVidia+OpenCL.

I can set up exclusive compute mode (page 74 from cuda programming guide 3.0) with nvidia-smi on a nvidia-gpu . that means, only one program can compute on gpu.

cuda runtime schedules than app automatically.

but I have a problem with opencl-programs in this case:
if one application runs on a gpu with setted exclusive compute mode and second opencl-program calls `clGetDeviceInfo(..., CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE, ...)` with the same GPU is the `result == CL_TRUE`. After that if opencl-app tries to create a context on this device, than crashes the running app (both).

How can i find out an available GPU with OpenCL?

Thanks.

Comment: This is possibly a bug in the OpenCL implementation. try contacting nVidia about it or post the question in the nVidia forums where an nVidia developer might pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

clGetDeviceIds returns the number of devices and their device Ids. Then you can check if each of the device is available or not. Iam not sure if it would resolve the crash though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue where I wanted to find the best OpenCL device in a list. I couldn't find a solution so I've wrote one myself. It will try to create a context on a device. If it can't, it will try the next one.

It also supports multiple OpenCL platforms. You can choose between nvidia (gpu only), amd (gpu & cpu), intel (cpu) and apple (gpu & cpu).

You can find it on github: https://github.com/nbigaouette/oclutils/

I'm still looking for a better locking mechanism though.